# How could I define a tf.Variable in my own function in tensorlfow?

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def myfunction():
    return_variable = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.0, dtype=tf.float32)
    return return_variable

a = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(3, 2, 2))
a_variable = tf.Variable(a, tf.float32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print('a_variable')
    print(sess.run(a_variable))
    print('myfunction')
    print(sess.run(myfunction()))
```

I want to initialize a variable in my function. When I run my code, I get the error "Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_1". I want to know why the variable defined in function could't be initialized by 'tf.initialize_all_variables()'. How could I use a variable in my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable is only created when you call `myfunction()`, and initialized if it is already created when you run `tf.initialize_all_variables()`. So you just need to call `myfunction()` before initializing all your variables. Usually you build your whole graph, using `myfunction()` if you need, and then you initialize just before training, so you don't have any problem... Note that `myfunction()` creates a new (identical) variable each time you call it, it does not return pointers to the same underlying variable.

See the code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
def myfunction():
    return_variable = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.0, dtype=tf.float32)
    return return_variable
a = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(3, 2, 2))
a_variable = tf.Variable(a, tf.float32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = myfunction()   # Create variable x, not initialized yet
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())  # Initialize all variables that already exist in your graph, including x, but y does not exist yet
    print('a_variable')
    print(sess.run(a_variable))
    print('x')  
    print(sess.run(x))  # Works fine: x is initialized
    print('y')
    y = myfunction()    # Create variable y, not initialized
    print(sess.run(y))  # This crashes, because y is not initialized
```